# Android BLE not connecting correctly to device

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth

A bit of background first, I am using a RedBear Blend microcontroller to attempt to send data into an Android application over BLE for a University project which is utilising some Open Source Blood Glucose meter hardware and attempting to turn it into a "smart" device with a companion application to log the data.

This works fine when using the example RedBear chat app available here: https://github.com/RedBearLab/Android/tree/master/Examples/Chat

Logcat from the example application:

```
5-01 12:39:26.316 2753-2753/com.redbear.chat W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.redbear.chat-1/lib/arm
05-01 12:39:26.406 2753-2753/com.redbear.chat D/SecWifiDisplayUtil: Metadata value : none
05-01 12:39:26.406 2753-2753/com.redbear.chat D/ViewRootImpl: #1 mView = com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView{6a1bff8 I.E...... R.....ID 0,0-0,0}
05-01 12:39:26.406 2753-2861/com.redbear.chat D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
05-01 12:39:26.456 2753-2861/com.redbear.chat I/Adreno: QUALCOMM build                   : d842ad3, Ia10634f51b
                                                        Build Date                       : 01/04/16
                                                        OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: XE031.06.00.05
                                                        Local Branch                     : mybranch17578993
                                                        Remote Branch                    : quic/LA.BF.2.1.2_rb1.7
                                                        Remote Branch                    : NONE
                                                        Reconstruct Branch               : NOTHING
05-01 12:39:26.456 2753-2861/com.redbear.chat D/libEGL: eglInitialize EGLDisplay = 0xae1e87c4
05-01 12:39:26.456 2753-2861/com.redbear.chat I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
05-01 12:39:26.486 2753-2753/com.redbear.chat D/BluetoothGatt: connect() - device: F0:44:62:58:BB:ED, auto: false
05-01 12:39:26.486 2753-2753/com.redbear.chat D/BluetoothGatt: registerApp()
05-01 12:39:26.486 2753-2753/com.redbear.chat D/BluetoothGatt: registerApp() - UUID=345487dc-e3ef-4a26-866c-b504f43c14c3
05-01 12:39:26.526 2753-2753/com.redbear.chat D/RBLService: Trying to create a new connection.
05-01 12:39:26.526 2753-2769/com.redbear.chat D/BluetoothGatt: onClientRegistered() - status=0 clientIf=5
05-01 12:39:26.536 2753-2753/com.redbear.chat W/DisplayListCanvas: DisplayListCanvas is started on unbinded RenderNode (without mOwningView)
05-01 12:39:26.536 2753-2753/com.redbear.chat W/DisplayListCanvas: DisplayListCanvas is started on unbinded RenderNode (without mOwningView)
05-01 12:39:26.546 2753-2861/com.redbear.chat D/libGLESv1: DTS_GLAPI : DTS is not allowed for Package : com.redbear.chat
05-01 12:39:26.576 2753-2861/com.redbear.chat V/RenderScript: 0x9e09e000 Launching thread(s), CPUs 4
05-01 12:39:26.586 2753-2753/com.redbear.chat D/ViewRootImpl: MSG_RESIZED_REPORT: ci=Rect(0, 96 - 0, 0) vi=Rect(0, 96 - 0, 0) or=1
05-01 12:39:26.606 2753-2753/com.redbear.chat I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@ca8aa6a time:49435618
05-01 12:39:26.726 2753-2753/com.redbear.chat D/ViewRootImpl: MSG_RESIZED: ci=Rect(0, 96 - 0, 996) vi=Rect(0, 96 - 0, 996) or=1
05-01 12:39:28.976 2753-2809/com.redbear.chat D/BluetoothGatt: onClientConnectionState() - status=0 clientIf=5 device=F0:44:62:58:BB:ED
05-01 12:39:28.986 2753-2809/com.redbear.chat I/RBLService: Connected to GATT server.
05-01 12:39:28.996 2753-2809/com.redbear.chat D/BluetoothGatt: discoverServices() - device: F0:44:62:58:BB:ED
05-01 12:39:28.996 2753-2809/com.redbear.chat I/RBLService: Attempting to start service discovery:true
05-01 12:39:29.276 2753-2768/com.redbear.chat D/BluetoothGatt: onClientConnParamsChanged() - Device=F0:44:62:58:BB:ED interval=6 status=0
05-01 12:39:29.536 2753-2768/com.redbear.chat D/BluetoothGatt: onSearchComplete() = Device=F0:44:62:58:BB:ED Status=0
05-01 12:39:29.536 2753-2753/com.redbear.chat D/BluetoothGatt: setCharacteristicNotification() - uuid: 713d0002-503e-4c75-ba94-3148f18d941e enable: true
05-01 12:39:29.566 2753-2809/com.redbear.chat D/BluetoothGatt: onClientConnParamsChanged() - Device=F0:44:62:58:BB:ED interval=39 status=0
05-01 12:39:34.846 2753-2769/com.redbear.chat D/BluetoothGatt: onClientConnParamsChanged() - Device=F0:44:62:58:BB:ED interval=18 status=0
05-01 12:40:25.866 2753-2753/com.redbear.chat V/ActivityThread: updateVisibility : ActivityRecord{f85a5ca token=android.os.BinderProxy@ca8aa6a {com.redbear.chat/com.redbear.chat.Chat}} show : true
05-01 12:40:31.266 2753-2753/com.redbear.chat D/ViewRootImpl: MSG_RESIZED_REPORT: ci=Rect(0, 96 - 0, 1092) vi=Rect(0, 96 - 0, 1092) or=1
05-01 12:40:31.296 2753-2753/com.redbear.chat D/ViewRootImpl: MSG_RESIZED_REPORT: ci=Rect(0, 96 - 0, 0) vi=Rect(0, 96 - 0, 0) or=1
```

However when I am trying to port the functionality into my application it looks as though they are not correctly connecting as I do not get the same output to logcat, instead the application crashes with a null pointer exception as the connection hasn't properly initialised. So I'm not sure what I'm doing incorrectly, in order to get the devices to successfully connect.

I have attempted to port the functionality from the example into my application in the following files:

```
MainActivity.java
Device.java
StoreReading.java
TakeReading.java
```

The application is on my github. https://github.com/rowmanns/android_ble/tree/master/BloodGlucoseV3

```
05-01 13:03:57.606 25495-25495/com.fyp.rowan.bloodglucosev3 D/ViewRootImpl: #1 mView = com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView{1186991 I.E...... R.....ID 0,0-0,0}
05-01 13:03:57.616 25495-25645/com.fyp.rowan.bloodglucosev3 D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
05-01 13:03:57.646 25495-25645/com.fyp.rowan.bloodglucosev3 I/Adreno: QUALCOMM build                   : d842ad3, Ia10634f51b
                                                                      Build Date                       : 01/04/16
                                                                      OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: XE031.06.00.05
                                                                      Local Branch                     : mybranch17578993
                                                                      Remote Branch                    : quic/LA.BF.2.1.2_rb1.7
                                                                      Remote Branch                    : NONE
                                                                      Reconstruct Branch               : NOTHING
05-01 13:03:57.646 25495-25645/com.fyp.rowan.bloodglucosev3 D/libEGL: eglInitialize EGLDisplay = 0x9f7ff7c4
05-01 13:03:57.646 25495-25645/com.fyp.rowan.bloodglucosev3 I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
05-01 13:03:57.676 25495-25495/com.fyp.rowan.bloodglucosev3 D/ViewRootImpl: MSG_RESIZED_REPORT: ci=Rect(0, 96 - 0, 0) vi=Rect(0, 96 - 0, 0) or=1
05-01 13:03:57.686 25495-25495/com.fyp.rowan.bloodglucosev3 W/DisplayListCanvas: DisplayListCanvas is started on unbinded RenderNode (without mOwningView)
05-01 13:03:57.686 25495-25645/com.fyp.rowan.bloodglucosev3 D/libGLESv1: DTS_GLAPI : DTS is not allowed for Package : com.fyp.rowan.bloodglucosev3
05-01 13:03:57.716 25495-25495/com.fyp.rowan.bloodglucosev3 I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@49e44d2 time:50906726
05-01 13:04:00.116 25495-25495/com.fyp.rowan.bloodglucosev3 D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
05-01 13:04:00.206 25495-25495/com.fyp.rowan.bloodglucosev3 D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
05-01 13:04:00.216 25495-25495/com.fyp.rowan.bloodglucosev3 I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_launch_request id:com.fyp.rowan.bloodglucosev3 time:50909220
05-01 13:04:00.266 25495-25495/com.fyp.rowan.bloodglucosev3 I/ToolbarWidgetWrapper: Progress display unsupported
05-01 13:04:00.286 25495-25731/com.fyp.rowan.bloodglucosev3 D/BluetoothAdapter: startLeScan(): null
05-01 13:04:00.286 25495-25731/com.fyp.rowan.bloodglucosev3 D/BluetoothAdapter: STATE_ON
05-01 13:04:00.286 25495-25731/com.fyp.rowan.bloodglucosev3 D/BluetoothAdapter: STATE_ON
05-01 13:04:00.286 25495-25731/com.fyp.rowan.bloodglucosev3 D/BluetoothLeScanner: Start Scan
05-01 13:04:00.286 25495-25731/com.fyp.rowan.bloodglucosev3 D/BluetoothAdapter: STATE_ON
05-01 13:04:00.296 25495-25731/com.fyp.rowan.bloodglucosev3 D/BluetoothAdapter: STATE_ON
05-01 13:04:00.296 25495-25731/com.fyp.rowan.bloodglucosev3 D/BluetoothAdapter: STATE_ON
05-01 13:04:00.296 25495-25731/com.fyp.rowan.bloodglucosev3 D/BluetoothAdapter: STATE_ON
05-01 13:04:00.306 25495-25495/com.fyp.rowan.bloodglucosev3 D/SecWifiDisplayUtil: Metadata value : none
05-01 13:04:00.316 25495-25495/com.fyp.rowan.bloodglucosev3 D/ViewRootImpl: #1 mView = com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView{948186d V.E...... R.....I. 0,0-0,0}
05-01 13:04:00.326 25495-25495/com.fyp.rowan.bloodglucosev3 D/ViewRootImpl: #1 mView = com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView{358dc4c I.E...... R.....ID 0,0-0,0}
05-01 13:04:00.336 25495-25583/com.fyp.rowan.bloodglucosev3 D/BluetoothLeScanner: onClientRegistered() - status=0 clientIf=5
05-01 13:04:00.406 25495-25495/com.fyp.rowan.bloodglucosev3 D/ViewRootImpl: MSG_RESIZED_REPORT: ci=Rect(0, 0 - 0, 0) vi=Rect(0, 0 - 0, 0) or=1
05-01 13:04:00.406 25495-25495/com.fyp.rowan.bloodglucosev3 W/DisplayListCanvas: DisplayListCanvas is started on unbinded RenderNode (without mOwningView)
05-01 13:04:00.426 25495-25506/com.fyp.rowan.bloodglucosev3 D/ScanRecord: parseFromBytes
05-01 13:04:00.426 25495-25495/com.fyp.rowan.bloodglucosev3 W/DisplayListCanvas: DisplayListCanvas is started on unbinded RenderNode (without mOwningView)
05-01 13:04:00.436 25495-25495/com.fyp.rowan.bloodglucosev3 D/ViewRootImpl: MSG_RESIZED_REPORT: ci=Rect(0, 96 - 0, 0) vi=Rect(0, 96 - 0, 0) or=1
05-01 13:04:00.466 25495-25645/com.fyp.rowan.bloodglucosev3 D/OpenGLRenderer: endAllActiveAnimators on 0xb2b49680 (RippleDrawable) with handle 0xa91ee510
05-01 13:04:00.466 25495-25507/com.fyp.rowan.bloodglucosev3 D/ScanRecord: parseFromBytes
05-01 13:04:00.476 25495-25495/com.fyp.rowan.bloodglucosev3 I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@bac547f time:50909481
05-01 13:04:00.526 25495-25588/com.fyp.rowan.bloodglucosev3 D/ScanRecord: parseFromBytes
05-01 13:04:00.576 25495-25583/com.fyp.rowan.bloodglucosev3 D/ScanRecord: parseFromBytes
05-01 13:04:00.626 25495-25506/com.fyp.rowan.bloodglucosev3 D/ScanRecord: parseFromBytes
05-01 13:04:00.686 25495-25507/com.fyp.rowan.bloodglucosev3 D/ScanRecord: parseFromBytes
05-01 13:04:00.726 25495-25495/com.fyp.rowan.bloodglucosev3 V/ActivityThread: updateVisibility : ActivityRecord{c3a515a token=android.os.BinderProxy@49e44d2 {com.fyp.rowan.bloodglucosev3/com.fyp.rowan.bloodglucosev3.MainActivity}} show : false
05-01 13:04:00.746 25495-25507/com.fyp.rowan.bloodglucosev3 D/ScanRecord: parseFromBytes
05-01 13:04:00.846 25495-25507/com.fyp.rowan.bloodglucosev3 D/ScanRecord: parseFromBytes
05-01 13:04:00.896 25495-25507/com.fyp.rowan.bloodglucosev3 D/ScanRecord: parseFromBytes
05-01 13:04:00.956 25495-25506/com.fyp.rowan.bloodglucosev3 D/ScanRecord: parseFromBytes
05-01 13:04:01.016 25495-25506/com.fyp.rowan.bloodglucosev3 D/ScanRecord: parseFromBytes
05-01 13:04:01.076 25495-25588/com.fyp.rowan.bloodglucosev3 D/ScanRecord: parseFromBytes
05-01 13:04:01.136 25495-25583/com.fyp.rowan.bloodglucosev3 D/ScanRecord: parseFromBytes
05-01 13:04:01.196 25495-25583/com.fyp.rowan.bloodglucosev3 D/ScanRecord: parseFromBytes
05-01 13:04:01.276 25495-25583/com.fyp.rowan.bloodglucosev3 D/ScanRecord: parseFromBytes
05-01 13:04:01.326 25495-25506/com.fyp.rowan.bloodglucosev3 D/ScanRecord: parseFromBytes
05-01 13:04:01.366 25495-25507/com.fyp.rowan.bloodglucosev3 D/ScanRecord: parseFromBytes
05-01 13:04:01.416 25495-25507/com.fyp.rowan.bloodglucosev3 D/ScanRecord: parseFromBytes
05-01 13:04:01.476 25495-25588/com.fyp.rowan.bloodglucosev3 D/ScanRecord: parseFromBytes
05-01 13:04:01.536 25495-25588/com.fyp.rowan.bloodglucosev3 D/ScanRecord: parseFromBytes
05-01 13:04:01.586 25495-25506/com.fyp.rowan.bloodglucosev3 D/ScanRecord: parseFromBytes
05-01 13:04:01.646 25495-25506/com.fyp.rowan.bloodglucosev3 D/ScanRecord: parseFromBytes
05-01 13:04:01.696 25495-25506/com.fyp.rowan.bloodglucosev3 D/ScanRecord: parseFromBytes
05-01 13:04:01.746 25495-25506/com.fyp.rowan.bloodglucosev3 D/ScanRecord: parseFromBytes
05-01 13:04:01.806 25495-25506/com.fyp.rowan.bloodglucosev3 D/ScanRecord: parseFromBytes
05-01 13:04:01.866 25495-25588/com.fyp.rowan.bloodglucosev3 D/ScanRecord: parseFromBytes
05-01 13:04:01.926 25495-25588/com.fyp.rowan.bloodglucosev3 D/ScanRecord: parseFromBytes
05-01 13:04:01.966 25495-25588/com.fyp.rowan.bloodglucosev3 D/ScanRecord: parseFromBytes
05-01 13:04:02.026 25495-25506/com.fyp.rowan.bloodglucosev3 D/ScanRecord: parseFromBytes
05-01 13:04:02.146 25495-25506/com.fyp.rowan.bloodglucosev3 D/ScanRecord: parseFromBytes
05-01 13:04:02.206 25495-25506/com.fyp.rowan.bloodglucosev3 D/ScanRecord: parseFromBytes
05-01 13:04:02.266 25495-25583/com.fyp.rowan.bloodglucosev3 D/ScanRecord: parseFromBytes
05-01 13:04:02.316 25495-25583/com.fyp.rowan.bloodglucosev3 D/ScanRecord: parseFromBytes
05-01 13:04:02.376 25495-25588/com.fyp.rowan.bloodglucosev3 D/ScanRecord: parseFromBytes
05-01 13:04:02.436 25495-25507/com.fyp.rowan.bloodglucosev3 D/ScanRecord: parseFromBytes
05-01 13:04:02.486 25495-25507/com.fyp.rowan.bloodglucosev3 D/ScanRecord: parseFromBytes
05-01 13:04:02.546 25495-25507/com.fyp.rowan.bloodglucosev3 D/ScanRecord: parseFromBytes
05-01 13:04:02.606 25495-25506/com.fyp.rowan.bloodglucosev3 D/ScanRecord: parseFromBytes
05-01 13:04:02.646 25495-25506/com.fyp.rowan.bloodglucosev3 D/ScanRecord: parseFromBytes
05-01 13:04:02.696 25495-25506/com.fyp.rowan.bloodglucosev3 D/ScanRecord: parseFromBytes
05-01 13:04:02.756 25495-25507/com.fyp.rowan.bloodglucosev3 D/ScanRecord: parseFromBytes
05-01 13:04:02.816 25495-25583/com.fyp.rowan.bloodglucosev3 D/ScanRecord: parseFromBytes
05-01 13:04:02.876 25495-25506/com.fyp.rowan.bloodglucosev3 D/ScanRecord: parseFromBytes
05-01 13:04:02.926 25495-25506/com.fyp.rowan.bloodglucosev3 D/ScanRecord: parseFromBytes
05-01 13:04:02.986 25495-25506/com.fyp.rowan.bloodglucosev3 D/ScanRecord: parseFromBytes
05-01 13:04:03.046 25495-25583/com.fyp.rowan.bloodglucosev3 D/ScanRecord: parseFromBytes
05-01 13:04:03.106 25495-25583/com.fyp.rowan.bloodglucosev3 D/ScanRecord: parseFromBytes
05-01 13:04:03.166 25495-25507/com.fyp.rowan.bloodglucosev3 D/ScanRecord: parseFromBytes
05-01 13:04:03.216 25495-25507/com.fyp.rowan.bloodglucosev3 D/ScanRecord: parseFromBytes
05-01 13:04:03.286 25495-25506/com.fyp.rowan.bloodglucosev3 D/ScanRecord: parseFromBytes
05-01 13:04:03.326 25495-25733/com.fyp.rowan.bloodglucosev3 I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_launch_request id:com.fyp.rowan.bloodglucosev3 time:50912335
05-01 13:04:03.336 25495-25583/com.fyp.rowan.bloodglucosev3 D/ScanRecord: parseFromBytes
05-01 13:04:03.346 25495-25731/com.fyp.rowan.bloodglucosev3 D/BluetoothAdapter: stopLeScan()
05-01 13:04:03.346 25495-25731/com.fyp.rowan.bloodglucosev3 D/BluetoothAdapter: STATE_ON
05-01 13:04:03.346 25495-25731/com.fyp.rowan.bloodglucosev3 D/BluetoothAdapter: STATE_ON
05-01 13:04:03.346 25495-25731/com.fyp.rowan.bloodglucosev3 D/BluetoothAdapter: STATE_ON
05-01 13:04:03.356 25495-25731/com.fyp.rowan.bloodglucosev3 D/BluetoothAdapter: STATE_ON
05-01 13:04:03.356 25495-25731/com.fyp.rowan.bloodglucosev3 D/BluetoothLeScanner: Stop Scan
05-01 13:04:03.396 25495-25495/com.fyp.rowan.bloodglucosev3 D/ViewRootImpl: #3 mView = null
05-01 13:04:03.406 25495-25495/com.fyp.rowan.bloodglucosev3 E/ViewRootImpl: sendUserActionEvent() mView == null
05-01 13:04:03.426 25495-25495/com.fyp.rowan.bloodglucosev3 D/AbsListView: Get MotionRecognitionManager
05-01 13:04:03.426 25495-25495/com.fyp.rowan.bloodglucosev3 E/MotionRecognitionManager: mSContextService = android.hardware.scontext.ISContextService$Stub$Proxy@35944f3
05-01 13:04:03.436 25495-25495/com.fyp.rowan.bloodglucosev3 E/MotionRecognitionManager: motionService = com.samsung.android.motion.IMotionRecognitionService$Stub$Proxy@393d4f
05-01 13:04:03.436 25495-25495/com.fyp.rowan.bloodglucosev3 E/MotionRecognitionManager: motionService = com.samsung.android.motion.IMotionRecognitionService$Stub$Proxy@393d4f
05-01 13:04:03.436 25495-25495/com.fyp.rowan.bloodglucosev3 D/SecWifiDisplayUtil: Metadata value : none
05-01 13:04:03.436 25495-25495/com.fyp.rowan.bloodglucosev3 D/ViewRootImpl: #1 mView = com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView{1765f6b I.E...... R.....ID 0,0-0,0}
05-01 13:04:03.486 25495-25495/com.fyp.rowan.bloodglucosev3 W/DisplayListCanvas: DisplayListCanvas is started on unbinded RenderNode (without mOwningView)
05-01 13:04:03.496 25495-25495/com.fyp.rowan.bloodglucosev3 D/ViewRootImpl: MSG_RESIZED_REPORT: ci=Rect(0, 96 - 0, 0) vi=Rect(0, 96 - 0, 0) or=1
05-01 13:04:03.536 25495-25495/com.fyp.rowan.bloodglucosev3 I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@81584ba time:50912545
05-01 13:04:03.756 25495-25495/com.fyp.rowan.bloodglucosev3 V/ActivityThread: updateVisibility : ActivityRecord{fbc0c5e token=android.os.BinderProxy@bac547f {com.fyp.rowan.bloodglucosev3/com.fyp.rowan.bloodglucosev3.TakeReading}} show : false
05-01 13:04:04.976 25495-25495/com.fyp.rowan.bloodglucosev3 D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
05-01 13:04:05.076 25495-25495/com.fyp.rowan.bloodglucosev3 D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
05-01 13:04:05.156 25495-25495/com.fyp.rowan.bloodglucosev3 I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_launch_request id:com.fyp.rowan.bloodglucosev3 time:50914163
05-01 13:04:05.236 25495-25495/com.fyp.rowan.bloodglucosev3 D/SecWifiDisplayUtil: Metadata value : none
05-01 13:04:05.236 25495-25495/com.fyp.rowan.bloodglucosev3 D/ViewRootImpl: #1 mView = com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView{5f5d546 I.E...... R.....ID 0,0-0,0}
05-01 13:04:05.296 25495-25495/com.fyp.rowan.bloodglucosev3 W/DisplayListCanvas: DisplayListCanvas is started on unbinded RenderNode (without mOwningView)
05-01 13:04:05.296 25495-25495/com.fyp.rowan.bloodglucosev3 W/DisplayListCanvas: DisplayListCanvas is started on unbinded RenderNode (without mOwningView)
05-01 13:04:05.316 25495-25495/com.fyp.rowan.bloodglucosev3 D/ViewRootImpl: MSG_RESIZED_REPORT: ci=Rect(0, 96 - 0, 0) vi=Rect(0, 96 - 0, 0) or=1
05-01 13:04:05.336 25495-25495/com.fyp.rowan.bloodglucosev3 W/DisplayListCanvas: DisplayListCanvas is started on unbinded RenderNode (without mOwningView)
05-01 13:04:05.356 25495-25645/com.fyp.rowan.bloodglucosev3 D/OpenGLRenderer: endAllActiveAnimators on 0x9b0cc680 (ListView) with handle 0x9d855ee0
05-01 13:04:05.356 25495-25495/com.fyp.rowan.bloodglucosev3 I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@3d1f88 time:50914367
05-01 13:04:05.496 25495-25495/com.fyp.rowan.bloodglucosev3 D/ViewRootImpl: MSG_RESIZED: ci=Rect(0, 96 - 0, 996) vi=Rect(0, 96 - 0, 996) or=1
05-01 13:04:05.586 25495-25495/com.fyp.rowan.bloodglucosev3 W/DisplayListCanvas: DisplayListCanvas is started on unbinded RenderNode (without mOwningView)
05-01 13:04:05.606 25495-25495/com.fyp.rowan.bloodglucosev3 D/ViewRootImpl: #3 mView = null
05-01 13:04:16.176 25495-25495/com.fyp.rowan.bloodglucosev3 D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
05-01 13:04:16.186 25495-25495/com.fyp.rowan.bloodglucosev3 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                              Process: com.fyp.rowan.bloodglucosev3, PID: 25495
                                                                              java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to destroy activity {com.fyp.rowan.bloodglucosev3/com.fyp.rowan.bloodglucosev3.StoreReading}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.fyp.rowan.bloodglucosev3.RBLService.disconnect()' on a null object reference
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:5062)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:5085)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:5348)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1200(ActivityThread.java:221)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1800)
                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7225)
                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
                                                                               Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.fyp.rowan.bloodglucosev3.RBLService.disconnect()' on a null object reference
                                                                                  at com.fyp.rowan.bloodglucosev3.StoreReading.onDestroy(StoreReading.java:155)
                                                                                  at android.app.Activity.performDestroy(Activity.java:7102)
                                                                                  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnDestroy(Instrumentation.java:1170)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:5040)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:5085) 
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:5348) 
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1200(ActivityThread.java:221) 
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1800) 
                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158) 
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7225) 
                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

Any help/ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You get a null pointer exception. You should make sure you don't call methods on an object that might be null. In your code, the variable gets set to an object only if the service binding succeeds. When it unbinds, it gets set to null.

Comment: Sure, thanks I understand. However I'm unsure as to why the devices are not connecting in the first place.. As far as I can tell I am doing it in the same way as the example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, with some help I figured out what was causing this issue today.

It turns out that bindService() was silently failing.

```
bindService(new Intent(this, RBLService.class), mServiceConnection, BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
```

This was due to me not listing the RBLService in the manifest file. (A simple newbie error on my part...)

Once this service was listed in the manifest file, it works as intended.

```
service
        android:name="com.fyp.rowan.bloodglucosev3.RBLService"
        android:enabled="true" />
```